# SSIS + Excel Vs_needsnewmetadata error

Tags: excel, ssis

I'm working in a project to load data from sqls erver into an excel file.
When working in my local machine, the package I'm working on is working perfectly.

However when I do a deployment I'm getting the error : failed validation and returned validation status "vs_neednewmetadata"

I'm using SSIS 2012 and Excel 2016

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: The excel driver works out datatypes on the fly. If a column is a certain length it makes it a varchar. If the column data is longer it makes it a memo. So depending on what data is in your file, it will change the datatypes on the file and throw this "vs_neednewmetadata". I've never found a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issues is always very complex to figure out.
Still when you have like this issue try to find if your sources or destinations have changed but not your deployed package. Indeed, when you update your connection tables DB or files please be sure that you deploy again
Also, you have to be carefull when you work with script component do not copy/past this component from others packages otherwise you will get the metadata error and you cannot resolve it.
In my case, the issue I had was related to destination Excel file. I have changed this file like erasing some lines, but I do not change its structure and I missed to copie this one in the server. 
That mean event the changes are minor and do not affect the structure of the destination file, you have to update your server version file with the one you use in dev.